# rails Uninitialized constant db:seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to seed my rails api, I've migrated the scaffolds and I can create the entries on my localhost.
I've also tried changing it to Person, and Car for each model but that doesn't work either.

my seed.rb:

```
People.create![
    {firstname: 'Josh', lastname: 'Brolin', email: 'jb@gmail.com'},
    {firstname: 'Emily', lastname: 'Blunt', email: 'EmilyB@gmail.com'},
    {firstname: 'Benicio', lastname: 'Del-Toro', email: 'Sicario@gmail.com'}
]

Cars.create![
    {year: '2019', make: 'Audi', model: 'R8', price: '167000', person_id: '1'},
    {year: '2010', make: 'Toyota', model: 'Camry', price: '6500', person_id: '2'},
    {year: '2009', make: 'Honda', model: 'Civic', price: '4500', person_id: '3'},
    {year: '2017', make: 'BMW', model: 'X5', price: '15000', person_id: '2'}
]
```

I'm getting this error when I run `rails db:seed`:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant People
/home/pat/Desktop/test/carpeopleback/db/seeds.rb:9:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
```

I've tried changing it to Person, and Car for each model but that doesn't work either. I've also tried running `rails db:setup` with the same results

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

edit: this is my schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema[7.0].define(version: 2022_03_11_224419) do
  create_table "cars", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "year"
    t.string "make"
    t.string "model"
    t.integer "price"
    t.integer "person_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "people", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "firstname"
    t.string "lastname"
    t.string "email"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

Comment: People = [
    {firstname: 'Josh', lastname: 'Brolin', email: 'jb@gmail.com'},
    {firstname: 'Emily', lastname: 'Blunt', email: 'EmilyB@gmail.com'},
    {firstname: 'Benicio', lastname: 'Del-Toro', email: 'Sicario@gmail.com'}
]
People.each do |p|
  Person.create! p
end

Comment: align the above code and it should work use same logic for cars

Comment: If we follow the conventions the model should be "Person". Loop the array of hashes and create the Person one by one (not 3 at once)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
People = [ {firstname: 'Josh', lastname: 'Brolin', email: 'jb@gmail.com'}, {firstname: 'Emily', lastname: 'Blunt', email: 'EmilyB@gmail.com'}, {firstname: 'Benicio', lastname: 'Del-Toro', email: 'Sicario@gmail.com'} ]
People.each do |p| 
  Person.create! p 
end
```

Check your model name as well it should be Person